# Limitted character input

Tags: html, css, reactjs, input, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to create input limitted to only 4 characters using reactjs semantic ui, I have tried a lot of ways of doing that but none of them seems to work.

```
<Input fluid
  value={this.state.code}
  type="text"
  minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10"
  placeholder={t('Code')}
  onChange={this.onCodeChange.bind(this)}
  error={this.state.formErrorsKeys.code}
/>
```

Also I'm thinking if it's possible to make an input splitted into 4 input areas.

Cheers!

Comment: What kind of `Input` component are you using, there? maybe it doesn't know `maxlength`? Anyway, you should check the length of the text in your `onCodeChange` function and control the length, there. It's the most reliable way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to add custom validation function which takes the input value and returns modified string.

Something like this:

```js
const validateField = string => {
    return string.slice(0, 4);
};

console.log(validateField('string')); // => 'stri'
console.log(validateField('test_test')); // => 'test'
```

Here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/r55228449p

**UPD**

> Also I'm thinking if it's possible to make an input splitted into 4
>   input areas

Updated the example to add something similar to "an input splitted into 4 input areas"

Answer (score 0):

React Semantic UI expects camel case `maxLength` and `minLength` props which will be passed to the html `input`. You are using all lowercase. Changing the prop names should fix your issue, however as others have said, a custom validator function may be appropriate.

Comment: Hmm, I've searched and did not found anithing like `maxLength` or `minLength`. I'm relying on this docs: https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/input/. Where can I found relevant info?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be in their documentation, but if you edit and try it with one of their examples it will work. Other libraries, like Ant Design are the same way.